# How to get the type of a variable with the address?

Tags: c++, pointers, types, memory-address

I'm trying to parse an DWARF-File. It is working but now I want to show the values in the correct format therefore the type of a symbol/variable is relevant. 
I have the address and the type as string of a symbol.

The bad solution:

```
if(symbol->getTypeAsString().contains("int")){
    int* intPtr = (int*)symbol->getAddressAsLong(); 
}    
else if(symbol->getTypeAsString().contains("double")){
    double* intPtr = (double*)symbol->getAddressAsLong();
}
```

Is it possible to detect the type of a symbol at a given address without a conditional constructs?

I would like to do something like this:

```
int var = 0x40E251;
auto* varPtr = (auto*)var;
std::cout << typeid(*varPtr).name() << std::endl;
```

Comment: What is the return type of `symbol->getAdress()`?

Comment: Can't you just add an ``enum`` in ``symbol`` corresponding to the type of the value ?

Comment: return type of getAdress() is from type long

Comment: Looks like you are using type erasure.  When working with that one normally uses the visitor pattern to make the decision.

Comment: Thank You for the input.
What should i do when the type is something like `map<int,MyObject, std::pair<int,double>>`

Comment: Re: "Is it possible to detect the type of a symbol at a given address without a conditional constructs?" The answer is unfortunately no.

Comment: Thank you @AndyG for the clear answer.